# Unknown (MEDIUMINT?) issue with Foreign Keys in Laravel 5.8 Migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am having trouble adding a MEDIUMINT foreign key constraint to a table.
I know it works, in the ***BASE TABLE*** the `organization_id` also references a MEDIUMINT. The first foreign key in the ***FOREIGN TABLE*** works, but the second does not.

Things I know for sure:

- both the parent table and the child table have `unsignedMediumInteger`;
- foreign column is created; and
- the key is added after the parent table and foreign column creation.

Things I have tried:

- changing `$table->unsignedMediumInteger('customer_id');` to `$table->mediumInteger('customer_id')->unsigned();`
- seperating the foreign key from the `Schema::create('numberblocks')` into `Schema::table('numberblocks')` on the same migration;
- changing the datatype to INT, SMALLINT;
- chaning the name from `customer_id` to `c_id` in the child table; and
- setting the foreign key to its own migration.

***BASE TABLE***

```
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedMediumInteger('organization_id');
            $table->unsignedMediumInteger('customer_id');
            $table->string('customer_domain');
            $table->timestamps();

            // Foreign Keys
            $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations');
        });
```

***FOREIGN TABLE***

```
        Schema::create('numberblocks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('group_id')->index();
            $table->unsignedMediumInteger('customer_id');
            $table->unsignedMediumInteger('order_id');
            $table->string('number', 15);
            $table->timestamps();

            // Foreign Keys
            $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups');
            $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('customer_id')->on('customers');
        });
```

Everything I have tried ends up with the same error:

````
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'db'.'#sql-1a78_2a6'
(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
(SQL: alter table 'numberblocks' add constraint 'numberblocks_customer_id_foreign'
foreign key ('customer_id') references 'customers' ('customer_id'))```
````

My question:
Does anyone else know a way to get this working?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes it will as the error says

> General error: 1822 Failed to add the foreign key constaint. Missing
>   index for constraint 'numberblocks_customer_id_foreign' in the refere
>   nced table 'customers'")

So try adding

```
$table->index(['customer_id']);
```

in the customers migration and will fix the issue

if not Kindly Comment below

Comment: Yes it did, thank you for the answer. I did not know you had to add an index to the parent.

Comment: yes its because its not auto increment